# android.view.InflateException, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory, inflate-exception, invocationtargetexception

I am facing these three errors that crash my App.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Some on this website suggested that the image file may be too large that causes the out of memory error which in turn causes the two other errors. The image I used is about 50KB, too small, I tried even a blank image of about 4KB but the problem is still there. Below is my code, could anyone please help me solve this problem.

```
public class occasions extends Activity {

TextView linkToPageTextView;
String LinkToPageTxt = "Click to visit Page";

ImageView headerImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridview_options);

    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    gridView.setNumColumns(2);

    headerImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header_img);
    headerImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stock);

    linkToPageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_page_text);
    linkToPageTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Do something
        }
    });
}

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ImageView option_picture;
    TextView option_name;

    public MyAdapter(Context context)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items.add(new Item("A", R.drawable.ps_tousled));
        items.add(new Item("B", R.drawable.ps_googiesdiner));
        items.add(new Item("C", R.drawable.ps_drugstore));
        items.add(new Item("D", R.drawable.ps_misc));       
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i)
    {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        return items.get(i).drawableId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        View v = view;

        if(v == null)
        {
           v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
           v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
           v.setTag(R.id.option_text, v.findViewById(R.id.option_text));
        }

        option_picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        option_name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.option_text);

        Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

        option_picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
        option_name.setText(item.name);

        option_name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent album_Activity = new Intent(occasions.this, 
                        GridViewActivity.class);

                if(i == 0)
                    {
                        album_Activity.putExtra("album_ID", "Series");
                }
                else if(i == 1)
                {
                    album_Activity.putExtra("album_ID", "Christmas");
                }
                else if(i == 2)
                {
                    album_Activity.putExtra("album_ID", "NY");

                }
                else if(i == 3)
                {

                    album_Activity.putExtra("album_ID", "Misc");
                }

                album_Activity.putExtra("sub_ID", 0);
                startActivity(album_Activity);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
}

private class Item
{
    final String name;
    final int drawableId;

    Item(String name, int drawableId)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }
}
}
```

and the xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:padding="5dp">

<com.jbd.abc.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="#55000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dip"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Did you Manage to solve it ?

Comment: @XcodeNOOB Yes I did. Please see my answer in the post below since I could not add the code properly here in this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(int filePath, int WIDTH, int HIGHT)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    //BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(_context.getResources().openRawResource(filePath),
            null,o);

    final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
    final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
    int scale = 1;
    while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
            && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
        scale *= 2;

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    //return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(_context.getResources().openRawResource(filePath),
            null, o2);
}
```

and adding the line to the manifest file.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```